# Find the vector in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ corresponding to $f$ as in the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem

I've been trying to get my head around the Riesz Representation Theorem and I'm stuck on this question.

> Let $N \in \mathbb N$ and define $f: \ell^2(\mathbb N) \to \mathbb R$ by $f((a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}=a_N $.
>
> 1) Prove that $f$ is continuous linear functional on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and 2) find the vector in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ corresponding to $f$ as in the Riesz Representation Theorem.

I can do the first part 1) but part 2) is where I get stuck. I've looked up various proofs that involve integration but they don't really make sense to me.

What would be the easiest way to figure this out?

Any help would be great!

Comment: How about the vector $e_N?$

Comment: (1) follows from (2).

Comment: Apologies I have come back to this question and think I have done it all wrong, could either of you show me how to do part one(1)? Is it to do with boundedness implying continuity of the function?

Answer (score 2):

As $|f((a_n))| = |a_N| = \sqrt{a_N^2} \leq  \sqrt{\sum_{n= 1}^\infty a_n^2}= \|(a_n)\|_{l^2}$, $f$ is continuos.
Note now that 
$$f((a_n)) = \sum_{n= 1}^\infty a_n b_n  = \langle(a_n),(b_n)\rangle_{l^2},$$ where $b_n =0$ if $n\neq N$ and $b_N = 1$.